# www and non-www http requests to https://www with full path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I created redirect from non-www and www http request to https and www request that was quite easy. I used following rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

But now the problem is when someone enters old non-secure url like domain and project-about.html at the end .htaccess redirect to https but adds request at the end again so the request after the domain look like:

```
/project-about.htmlproject-about.html
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works very good even without additional redirect. Tested and confirmed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This method removes the need for an extra `RewriteRule` also, helping to speed up your website.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: @Igor This doesnt add an extra www to the request. Clear you caches.

Comment: Just as @starkeen said, and what I put in my answer, please clear your cache.